# RSpec nested if function

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to RSpec and I'm trying to do testing but I have no idea how to handle nested if. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

```
array1 = %w[a b]
array2 = %w[aa b c]
@a = if (array1 & array2).any?
       if !array2.include? 'c'
         'yes'
       else
         'no'
            end
     else
       'neither'
     end
puts @a
```

I would like to develop a basic test for my code using RSpec. My code runs perfectly I just don't know how to write a test.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question? What behavior are you getting with the above code and what behavior would you like instead?

Comment: RSpec and Rubocop are two different things. What's your question? What's the problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--you don't write a test for standalone code, you write a test for a method. To test you pass all combinations of parameters to exercise the function in question.

Comment: As @Dave advises you need to write your code as a method and then perform tests on the method. For example: `def m(arr1, arr2); return 'neither' if (arr1 & arr2).empty?; array2.include?('c') ? 'no' : 'yes'; end`. `return 'neither' if (arr1 & arr2).empty?` is called a *guard clause*. Its use reduces by one the number of levels of nested conditional statements. `array2.include?('c') ? 'no' : 'yes'` uses the [ternary operator](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly test nested if expressions. When you write a test, you're testing the code as a whole. In this case, you have 3 possible routes the code could take, in which case you would write 3 tests.

One test would satisfy `(array1 & array2).any? && !array2.include?('c')`, the second test would satisfy `(array1 & array2).any? && array2.include?('c')`, and the third test would satisfy `(array1 & array2).empty?`

So, for example...

```rb
def my_function(array1, array2)
  if (array1 & array2).any?
    if !array2.include? 'c'
      'yes'
    else
      'no'
    end
  else
    'neither'
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'MyFunction' do
  context 'array has c' do
    it 'should return no' do   #
      expect { my_function(['b'], ['b']) }.to eq("no")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfectly agree: name a function and test on that function.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand principle of testing! That's why I don't see any reference regarding on what I want.